# How can I bootstrap a Laravel application from within a Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring, bootstrapping

I am trying to build a proof of concept to solve the following problem:
I need to refactor a Kohana application into Laraval, but we keep adding new features and developing the application. So the Kohana and Laravel codebase have to work together for a while.

For a proof of concept, I take two Laravel applications where one of them simulates the old Kohana application.

A solution I have in mind is to create a Middleware or service provider in the Laravel application that checks if the route could be resolved in this Laravel. In the case it could not resolve the route, the other application should be bootstrapped to execute the request.

When I try to bootstrap the second Laravel from within a middleware class of the first one the following error appears:

```
Target class [App\Http\Middleware\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] does not exist.
```

On executing the following line:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

Middleware hanle function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();
    try {
        //route exists
        $routes->match($request);

        return $next($request);
    }
    catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e){
        //route doesn't exist

        // define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
        require_once env('LARAVEL_FILE_PATH').'/vendor/autoload.php';

        $app = require_once env('LARAVEL_FILE_PATH').'/bootstrap/app.php';

        $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

        $response = $kernel->handle(
            $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
        );

        $response->send();

        $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

        exit;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong or maybe have a suggestion for another solution?

Comment: Please clarify (and edit your title if necessary): are you trying to bootstrap Kohana from Laravel, Laravel from Kohana or Laravel from Laravel?

Comment: There is not much code in your question to work with, but did you add the Laravel packages and codebase to your composer.json?

Comment: @Jerodev what would you want me to add to the composer file exactly?

Comment: @Jerodev what code do you need to help me?

Comment: How is your application structured? Does the webserver point to the laravel application or the other one?

Comment: @Jerodev the webserver points to the first Laravel and bootstraps it. The second Laravel is located on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by de namespacing.

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

Should be

```
$kernel = $app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

This is also the case for

```
 $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
```